# Turing Machines

Tags: automata

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is a finite set and that $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ are Turing acceptable subsets of $\Sigma^*$ that satisfy the following properties:

1. $L_1 \cup L_2 \cup L_3 = \Sigma^*$;
2. $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_2 \cap L_3 = L_3 \cap L_1 = \varnothing$.

Show that $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ must all be recursive.

Comment: Can you prove the corresponding result for the case of two languages, $L_1$ and $L_2$, such that $L_1\cap L_2=\varnothing$ and $L_1\cup L_2=\Sigma^*$? That’s a very standard result, and at least one proof of it generalizes very easily to your problem.

Comment: I know that if L1 and L2 are recursive then L U P is also recursive and so is L1 ∩ L2 but I don't know how to go the other way around!

Comment: Suppose that $M_1,M_2$, and $M_3$ are Turing machines that accept $L_1,L_2$, and $L_3$, respectively. Do you know that there must be a Turing machine $M$ that simulates running $M_1,M_2$, and $M_3$ simultaneously on the input to $M$?